# How To Check Network Connectivity From Dll & Pass message to Main form

Tags: vb.net, dll

I want to make dll to check network availability. If Network not available I display message & if the message reply=Retry its check again after 5 seconds. With in the 5 seconds if the network established again exit from the dll & open the main form.

My problem is I cannot display message if the use press cancel to the retry message.

This is my sample code

Main Form

```
Private Sub Login_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Try

    
    clsConnectionAvailability.CheckNetworkConnectivity()

                txtUserName.Text = Environment.UserName
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

End Sub

This is my dll

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Public Class clsConnectionAvailability

```
Private Shared WithEvents WaitTimer As New Timer()
Private Shared intAlarmCounter As Integer = 1

Public Shared Sub CheckNetworkConnectivity(ByRef booExitFlag As Boolean)
    ' Checking Network Connectivity
    If Not NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable Then ' If Netowrk Connection Unavailable
        clsIsNetworkConnect.CheckNetWorkConnection(booExitFlag) ' Checking Network Connection Is Available or Retry Until Available
        MessageBox.Show(CStr(booExitFlag))
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

Public Class clsIsNetworkConnect

```
' Timer Inizialization Variables Declaration
Private Shared WithEvents WaitTimer As New Timer()
Private Shared intAlarmCounter As Integer = 1
Private Shared booExitFlag As Boolean = False

Public Shared Sub CheckNetWorkConnection(ByRef booExitFlag As Boolean)
    Try
        ' Time Event Inizialization
        With WaitTimer
            .Interval = 5000 ' TimerEventProcessor will Fire after { 5 Seconds }
            .Start()
        End With

        While booExitFlag = False
            ' After Interval fulfilled, TimerEventProcessor Fired
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Shared Sub TimerEventProcessor(ByVal myObject As Object, ByVal myEventArgs As EventArgs) Handles WaitTimer.Tick
    Try
        ' What to Do When Timer Interval Fulfilled ?
        WaitTimer.Stop()
        Dim msgConectResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Network Connectivity Unavailable." & vbCr & _
                                                              "Please Inform IT Department." & vbCr & _                                                                 
                                                              "Retry - Check For Network Connectivity Availability Again." & vbCr & _
                                                              "Cancel - Exit From The System.", & _
                                                              "Network Unavailable", _
                                                              MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, _
                                                              MessageBoxIcon.Information, _
                                                              MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) ' Display Message & Waiting for Reply
        If msgConectResult = DialogResult.Retry Then ' DialogResult = Retry
            If Not System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable Then ' If Netowrk Connection Unavailable
                intAlarmCounter += 1
                WaitTimer.Enabled = True
            Else ' If Network Connection Available
                booExitFlag = True
            End If
        Else ' DialogResult = Cancel
           booExitFlag = True
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Can anyone please help me to pass cancel message to main form.

Comment: New account same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634493/how-to-check-network-availability

Comment: A dll normally does not have a user interface. It would be odd to display a message box from a dll.

Comment: As I commented on your last question, it would be odd for a dll to Import System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Mary , Message display. I want to pass value to main form if user press Cancel on dll message.